# Database access from jsr-303 custom validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I'm using spring based validation in combination with hibernate validator enabled by the following in my application context:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        ....
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.factory" value-ref="validator" />    
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

I've implemented a custom validator that accesses a database to check validity constraints for a particular object using a spring injected DAO. This results in a java.lang.StackOverflowError as it appears that the validation is called every time an object is loaded from the database from within the validator, causing an infinite loop. To get around this, I have tried setting the flush mode on my entity manager to commit from within the validator with the following code:

```
entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

This results in an "collection not process by flush()" exception from hibernate.

Is there an example of best practice in accessing the database from within a custom validator which will allow me to get around both of these issues?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375704/make-custom-hibernate-validation-annotation-for-email-existence IMHP Spring way is to `@Autowired` service or DAO class to validator and use them as usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, it would appear that the best way to do this to is to use the EntityManagerFactory directly from within the code. In the initialize(...) method of the validator class I have the following code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu_name");
entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

The downside is that you don't get Spring's DI features, but you can access the database nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, here is how I solved it:
[@Autowired bean works with @Valid on controller but fails with CRUD repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490075/autowired-bean-works-with-valid-on-controller-but-fails-with-crud-repository/13924239#13924239)

In a few words, I also got a reference to the `EntityManagerFactory` object. However, I set `setFlushMode` to `FlushModeType.COMMIT` just before calling my service method. Finally I set it back to `FlushModeType.AUTO`:

Here is an example:

```
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername constraintAnnotation) {       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try { 
            em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);          
            return userService.findByUsername(username) == null;

            } finally { 
           em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
           }    
    }
}
```