# Make custom hibernate validation annotation for email existence

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

i was wondering if it's possible to make custom hibernate validation annotation
that will check in the database if the email exist or not (call dao method and return true if the email exist)

so i can do something like:

```
    @NotBlank(message = "email is required")
@Email(message = "{invalid.email}")
    @EmailExist(message = "{email.exist}")
@Column(name = "email", length = 155, nullable = false)       
private String email;
```

please advise with a sample if possible, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible, you just need to implement your custom annotation validator implementation.

If you use real AspectJ and annotate the class with `@Configurable` then you an use `@Inject` like in every other spring bean.

@See:

- Spring Configurable: [Spring Reference Chapter 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- [JSR-000303 Bean Validation 1.0 Final Release Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) Chapter 2 Constraint Definition
- [Example of an custom Validation](http://blog.m1key.me/2010/07/custom-validation-with-bean-validation.html)

Comment: any example for the Spring Configurable ?

Comment: spring roo makes havy use of it. so you just need to setup a spring roo projet with one entiti. The entiti will use that annotation.

Answer (score 1):

No need for AspectJ magic. If you are using spring, you just need to @Autowire -annotate your field, spring will inject the DAO. See Spring Reference [5.7.2.2 Configuring Custom Constraints](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints):

> By default, the LocalValidatorFactoryBean configures a
>   SpringConstraintValidatorFactory that uses Spring to create
>   ConstraintValidator instances. This allows your custom
>   ConstraintValidators to benefit from dependency injection like any
>   other Spring bean.

So your only job is to write the custom annotation. Easy to find samples on the web.

Comment: Care to provide an example?